# Restoring a Windows 7 backup onto Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have recently moved my main machine from Windows 7 to Server 2008 R2. Just before I did the install, I used the Windows Backup facility to create a backup on a file share.

I am now using the Server Backup facility in 2008 R2 to restore this and it is not working. When I use another Win7 machine, I point the restore program at the folder containing the backup fileset and it lets me look through them. In R2, I point it at the same folder and it tells me that "The specified remote share does not contain any backup."

I naively assumed that the two systems would be compatible, is this not the case? Is there anyway to get that data back again?

Answer (score 0):

When you make a backup I it creates a couple VHD files.  You should be able to simply mound one of those [VHD files](http://thelazyadmin.com/blogs/thelazyadmin/archive/2009/01/15/mount-a-vhd-within-windows-7-server-2008-r2.aspx) directly and get access to what you want.

Comment: does win7 create a vhd file, I know that w2k8r2 does but I'm not sure about win7.

Comment: @tony roth, It did when I ran a full backup of my workstation two weeks ago.

Comment: This was not a full backup, just a local user backup. It does not produce vhd's just lots and lots of what I presume are zip files.

Comment: If you can't come up with any other solution you could setup windows 7 in a VM temporarily to do your restore.

Comment: @Zoredache - That is the best I have come up with so far!

Comment: Windows 7 has a different backup/restore scheme then windows 2008, Windows 2008 is creating a VHD file which you can mount to a VM machine and open it, but with windows 7 backup, you must use windows 7 to restore it.